# PostgreSQL index in temporarly table

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgis

I have the following PostGIS/greSQL query

```
SELECT luc.*
FROM spatial_derived.lucas12 luc,
  (SELECT geom
   FROM spatial_derived.germany_bld
   WHERE state = 'SN') sn
WHERE ST_Contains(sn.geom, luc.geom)
```

*Query plan:*

```
Nested Loop  (cost=2.45..53.34 rows=8 width=236) (actual time=1.030..26.751 rows=1282 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on germany_bld  (cost=0.00..2.20 rows=1 width=18399) (actual time=0.023..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((state)::text = 'SN'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 15
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on lucas12 luc  (cost=2.45..51.06 rows=8 width=236) (actual time=1.002..26.031 rows=1282 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (germany_bld.geom ~ geom)
        Filter: _st_contains(germany_bld.geom, geom)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 499
        Heap Blocks: exact=174
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on lucas12_geom_idx  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=23 width=0) (actual time=0.419..0.419 rows=1781 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (germany_bld.geom ~ geom)
Planning time: 0.536 ms
Execution time: 27.023 ms
```

which is due to an index on the geometry columns pretty fast. However when I want to add a buffer to the sn polygon (1 big polygon that represents a border line, hence a quite simple feature):

```
SELECT luc.*
FROM spatial_derived.lucas12 luc,
  (SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 30000) geom
   FROM spatial_derived.germany_bld
   WHERE state = 'SN') sn
WHERE ST_Contains(sn.geom, luc.geom)
```

*Query plan:*

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..13234.80 rows=7818 width=236) (actual time=6221.391..1338380.257 rows=2298 loops=1)
  Join Filter: st_contains(st_buffer(germany_bld.geom, 30000::double precision), luc.geom)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 22637
  ->  Seq Scan on germany_bld  (cost=0.00..2.20 rows=1 width=18399) (actual time=0.018..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((state)::text = 'SN'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 15
  ->  Seq Scan on lucas12 luc  (cost=0.00..1270.55 rows=23455 width=236) (actual time=0.005..25.623 rows=24935 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.271 ms
Execution time: 1338381.079 ms
```

the query takes forever! I blame it on the not existing index in the temporally table sn. The massive decrease in speed can't be 'caused by `ST_Buffer()` as it's itself really fast and the buffered feature is simple.

Two Questions:

1) Am I right?

2) What can I do, to reach similar speed as with the first query?

Comment: please provide plans for both queries

Comment: added the query plans

Comment: Why use a subquery? You could use `... x JOIN y ON ST_contains(x.a, y.b) ...`

Comment: @wildplasser you're right, however using the wron function was the reason for the decrease in speed.

Comment: My guess is that ST_buffer() renders the join-condition non-sargeable, since it hides the indexed field inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ran into a trap. `ST_Buffer()` is not the right choice here rather `ST_DWithin()` which keeps the indexes of every geometry column when actually performing a bounding box comparison. The [help page](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html) for ST_Buffer() clearly states to not make the mistake using ST_Buffer(), but instead use ST_DWithin() for radius searches. Since the word **Buffer** is used in a lot of GIS softwares I didn't consider looking for alternatives.

```
SELECT luc.*
FROM spatial_derived.lucas12 luc
JOIN spatial_derived.germany_bld sn ON ST_DWithin(sn.geom, luc.geom, 30000)
WHERE bld.state = 'SN'
```

works and only takes a second (2300 points within that "buffer")!

Answer (score 0):

to check if you right, you can leave sn as is and apply `ST_Buffer` on join:

```
SELECT luc.*
FROM spatial_derived.lucas12 luc,
  (SELECT geom
   FROM spatial_derived.germany_bld
   WHERE state = 'SN') sn
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Buffer(sn.geom, 30000), luc.geom)
```

*Query plan:*

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..13234.80 rows=7818 width=236) (actual time=6237.876..1340000.576 rows=2298 loops=1)
  Join Filter: st_contains(st_buffer(germany_bld.geom, 30000::double precision), luc.geom)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 22637
  ->  Seq Scan on germany_bld  (cost=0.00..2.20 rows=1 width=18399) (actual time=0.023..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((state)::text = 'SN'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 15
  ->  Seq Scan on lucas12 luc  (cost=0.00..1270.55 rows=23455 width=236) (actual time=0.004..24.525 rows=24935 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.453 ms
Execution time: 1340001.420 ms
```

this query will answer both your questions or first, depending on result.

**Update**

1. Your assumption seems to be wrong. The `ST_Buffer()` causes speed drop down
2. You seem to join on much larger set when using the `ST_Buffer`, so time increase is quite expected. You can run `explain analyze` for both with and without `ST_Buffer()` queries - it probably will show same plans with different `rows` number and `cost` second value...

Comment: your solution takes 22min while the same query without `ST_Buffer()` takes 593msec. Still a way to huge difference.

Comment: When runing `SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 30000) FROM spatial_derived.germany_bld WHERE state = 'SN'` it also only takes 76msec. So is it really 'causing the speed drop down?
I will run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Comment: oh, yes please check with analyze for sure. if you have smth strange - dont ommit analyze

Comment: @andrasz please check plan for: ```with sn as (
  SELECT geom
    FROM spatial_derived.germany_bld
    WHERE state = 'SN'
)
SELECT luc.*
FROM spatial_derived.lucas12 luc
JOIN sn on sn.geom = luc.geom
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Buffer(sn.geom, 30000), luc.geom)```

Comment: this is really fast, however has no results

Comment: yeah, cos it joins on small set and after that no point in ST_Buffer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144452/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-andrasz).